# .Net Error System.ArgumentException: The value can not be null or string or empty in DataLayer

Tags: .net

I'm having the error "System.ArgumentException: The value can not be null or string or empty."
At the Line code

```
Public Sub New(ByVal databaseName As String)
            **db = New Database(databaseName)**
End Sub
```

Error Causing Sournce File is "C:\Company\Main\Source\DataLayer\Object2.vb"
Please find the screen shot.

Please could you help?

**Task Explanation**
Am trying to execute the "db_StoredProcedue" from the below function of mentioned root file.
C:\Company\Main\Source\Project\App_Code\Application\ResultDataset.vb

```
    Imports System.Web.UI
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.IO
    Imports Company.Web.TMSuite.Workflow
    Namespace Company.Web.TMSuite
    Public Class ResultDataset
        Inherits BasePage
        Public Shared Function GetResultsDataset() As DataSet
            Dim Obj1 As New Workflow(BasePage.DatabaseName)

            Dim ds As New DataSet

            ds = Obj1.GetResultDataset()

            Return ds

        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

**Obj1 file located in 
  C:\Company\Main\Source\Workflow\Object1.vb**

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports Company.Web.TMSuite.DataAccess
Imports Company.Web.TMSuite.TMSuiteComponents
Public Class Workflow
    Private objResultsData As ResultsData  

Public Sub New(ByVal databaseName As String)
    objMetricsData = New MetricsData(databaseName)
End Sub

Public Function Obj2() As DataSet
        Return objResultssData.Obj2()
    End Function
End Class
```

**Obj2 file located in 
  C:\Company\Main\Source\DataLayer\Object2.vb**

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data.Common
Imports Company.FoundationLibrary.Data
Imports Company.FoundationLibrary.ExceptionHandling
Imports Company.Web.TMSuite.DataAccess.ExceptionPolicies
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class ResultsData
    Inherits BaseData

    Public Sub New(ByVal databaseName As String)
        db = New Database(databaseName)  //Error Throughing at this line as -> ""System.ArgumentException: The value can not be null or string or empty.""
    End Sub

  Public Function Obj2() As DataSet
        Dim errorMessage As String = Nothing
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cmd As DbCommand

        ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        Try
            cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("db_StoredProcedue")

            db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "@pErrorMessage", DbType.String, ErrorMessageSize)

            ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd)

            If Not IsDBNull(db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "@pErrorMessage")) Then
                errorMessage = db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "@pErrorMessage")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            Dim blnRethrow As Boolean = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, DataAccessExceptionPolicy)

            If blnRethrow Then
                Throw
            End If
        End Try

        Return ds

    End Function
End Class
```

Please let me know, If I have to post additional code to resolv this issue.

Comment: The error message says some value is empty. In the line you mention there is one value (databasename). So what value is it and why is it that value?

Comment: That value to make a database connection, The database connection is passing from basepage.databasename in the firstclass.

Comment: That's what it *should* do, apparently. Try and debug this code and inspect what the value really is - the errormessage says it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got some typos in your code samples, but based on what I'm reading, I think you're failing to pass a database name into the constructor of your objResults class from the call in the Workflow class. It is provided implicitly as a null, which throws the exception.

I'm basing that on the inference that "Private objResultsData as ResultsData" is really supposed to be declared "Private objResultsData as objResults" *or* your objResults class is supposed to be declared as "ResultsData." If I've misunderstood the code, please accept my apologies.

**EDIT**: Based on OP feedback, the Workflow class needs a constructor and member field to contain the database name, which can then be used to explicitly initialize the ResultsData class and eliminate the problem. Hope that helps!

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports Company.Web.TMSuite.DataAccess
Imports Company.Web.TMSuite.TMSuiteComponents
Public Class Workflow
    Private databaseName as String
    Private objResultsData As ResultsData
    Public Sub New (DatabaseName as String)
        Me.databaseName = DatabaseName
    End Sub
    Public Function Obj2() As DataSet
        objResultsData = new ResultsData(Me.DatabaseName)
        Return objResultsData.Obj2() ' Alternate possibility is to pass the name as parm here
    End Function
End Class
```

You then need to modify your instantiation of Workflow to include the database name in the constructor, which passes it down the chain. Caveat is that the code above is untested, but should illustrate the relevant points for you.

Comment: Your understanding is perfect on this issue. Above post had some type issues. now I updated the post. Please find the updated post. Thank You

Comment: No problem! Have modified answer, hope this helps.

Comment: I tried with that code, Still throughing the same error and I have updated the Above Post as per you suggestions.

Comment: Now that I look at your code, you've changed some other dependent objects and added new references or names (MetricsData is/should be ResultsData?) that were not in the original problem, which is making it very difficult for me to keep up with constructive help. The bottom line is that you must pass the database name from the top-most call down to the object that requires it, and then ensure the Obj2 method uses that database name when the data access is attempted.

Comment: Thank you for being with me on this. Workflow, ResultsData classes are existing and working fine with other methods in the files **"C:\Company\Main\Source\Project\Forms\webpage.aspx.vb and webpage.vb "**. But I'm having the problem with **"C:\Company\Main\Source\Project\App_Code\Application\ResultDataset.vb "** file methods.

Answer (score 0):

Issue causing is:

For the methods in C:\Company\Main\Source\Project\Forms\webpage.aspx.vb and webpage.vb " accessing the database from basepage.databasename property

But for, we are not able to access the database from basepage.databasename property
C:\Company\Main\Source\Project\App_Code\Application\ResultDataset.vb

Comment: As I look further at your code, I'm not seeing any database connection methods (no Connection objects or even any evidence of contacting a database, just executing procedures), passing of any credentials or a connection string, so I believe there are other issues at hand here, as well, so I regret that I think I've helped as much as I can with the first-level problems that were evident (passing the database name down your object hierarchy). I hope I helped at least some.